# Calculate flag based on value of two other flags

Tags: python, pandas

I have three fields, client_id, flag_1 (0 or 1), and flag_2 (0 or 1). For every client, I need to calculate flag_3  which should equal 1 if both flag_1 == 1 and flag_2 ==1, otherwise 0.

I have tried:

```
df['flag_3'] = [1 if x==1 and y==1 else 0 for x in df['flag_1'] and y in df['flag_2']]

df['flag_3'] = np.where(df['flag_1'] == 1 and df['flag_2'] == 1, 1, 0)
```

...getting errors like "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous."

Comment: You need to use bitwise operator (&) instead of logical (and)

Comment: _...getting errors like "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous."_ Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Answer (score 1):

You are using boolean indexing to select rows and the index should be combined using binary "&"

```
df['flag_3'] = np.where((df['flag_1'] == 1) & (df['flag_2'] == 1), 1, 0)
```